# Auto fit md-tab to screen or container width in Angular2 Materials

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

**Hello guys,**

In angular2materials, i want to let md-tab width to fit the container or the screen width. (for example if id make md-tab-group with 2 md-tab, every md-tab should by 50vw or 50% of the container width) for the moment they have fixed width and i can't set the width from css. Any ideas ?

[see image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD8f5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS:

.md-tab-label

```
    flex: 1;
```

}

Comment: I believe md-tab is class name so it should start with a period (`.`). Also mark the content as code for proper appearance as code block.